# Uninstalling Parallels Desktop 14 - Aren't there drivers or kernel extensions too?

Tags: mac, parallels-desktop, macos

When installing Parallels Desktop For Mac version 14.1.3, I was prompted for a password. I assume that means some kernel extensions or drivers were installed into macOS.

The official [*Uninstall Parallels Desktop for Mac*](https://kb.parallels.com/en/124255) page says simply to discard the Parallels app.

➥ Does that mean some macOS alteration is left in place?

Also, according to [this page](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-parallels-on-mac) there is some other stuff left behind as well.

Comment: If you want to know what's associated with an App and where it is, that you want to uninstall, I've found [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) both informative and useful to clean up the cruft when uninstalling an App. Note that I have no affiliation with its developer and am just a user of the app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically a [customer support question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y).

Comment: Please be aware that the linked page primarily exists to sell a 3rd party app cleaner (ant that there is a difference between kexts and preferences somewhere in ~/Library

Comment: @nohillside, Parallels Desktop's kernel extensions are within its application bundle and [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) is free. If you just delete the application bundle, that is not everything, but what's left, sans the VMs and OS install media, is minor cruft.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for your Comment, as it gave me a clue about looking for .kext files. I wrote up my findings as an Answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Aren't there drivers or kernel extensions too?

Yes, apparently Parallels does use kernel extensions.

If in the Finder we select Parallels Desktop.app and context-click to choose `Show package contents`, we can navigate to nested folder `Contents` > `Library` > `Extensions` > `10.9` to find some `.kext` files such as `prl_hypervisor.kext`.

Are such kernel extensions copied somewhere else upon installation? Yes. Doing a `sudo find / -name prl_hypervisor.kext` in the Terminal.app shows two hits, one inside the app and one copied elsewhere into a `StagedExtensions` folder:

- /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/Extensions/10.9/prl_hypervisor.kext
- /Library/StagedExtensions/Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Library/Extensions/10.9/prl_hypervisor.kext

[image: screenshot of Finder showing path to .kext files made visible by choosing "Show package contents".]

I have not yet tried deleting the app via the Trash yet. So I do not know if doing so removes the copy as well as the original.

Comment: You said, "I have not yet tried deleting the app via the Trash yet. So I do not know if doing so removes the copy as well as the original." and if you just delete the /Applications/Parallels Desktop.app by placing it in the Trash and emptying it, then that is all that's deleted. As I've already mentioned, but appears to be overlooked by you, [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) is both informative and useful to clean up the cruft when uninstalling an App.

Comment: I sugget you to make a list of files you detected as installed by Parallels and then try https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/ . Then you will be able to check which method is the best.

Comment: You could also test this shell script:https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253217/31707 .

Comment: To remove those run `sudo kextcache --clear-staging`. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535279/what-is-library-stagedextensions-for-and-how-to-remove-extensions